# SSRS report not rendering in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

We have created few SSRS reports which have in turn been made available in an ASP.NET page using ReportViewer control.
The rendering time of reports vary from 8 min to 15 min (one huge report).

Note: The report has no grouping or heavy formatting.
The data is huge and query run time is huge.

These reports when run on ASP.NET website try to load but then no result is displayed and blank screen appears.

Resolutions tried:

•   Increased the execution timeout in Reporting Server Web

```
Config:<httpRuntime executionTimeout="36000" />
```

•   RsreportserverConfig changes:
`<Add Key="SecureConnectionLevel" Value="0"/>
    <Add Key="CleanupCycleMinutes" Value="36000"/>
    <Add Key="SQLCommandTimeoutSeconds" Value="0"/>
    <Add Key="MaxActiveReqForOneUser" Value="20"/>
    <Add Key="DatabaseQueryTimeout" Value="0"/>
    <Add Key="RunningRequestsScavengerCycle" Value="60"/>
    <Add Key="RunningRequestsDbCycle" Value="60"/>
    <Add Key="RunningRequestsAge" Value="30"/>
    <Add Key="MaxScheduleWait" Value="5"/>
    <Add Key="DisplayErrorLink" Value="true"/>
    <Add Key="WebServiceUseFileShareStorage" Value="false"/>`
•  Changed WebConfig of website to increase timeout:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="90000" executionTimeout="36000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I know this may be over simplifying it but I have had this bite be in the back side before. Do you have compatibility view settings in the browser set up for the site you are deployed to. In some cases the compatibility view settings will not allow the report to be rendered on screen. In some cases it simply blocks the loading icons and in other it just wont show anything at all.

Comment: Bu then why are other reports being rendered.This problem is only for a few.

Comment: Certain functionalities within SSRS do not "play nice" in browsers even in IE which is strange because they are both microsoft products. I have had it affect different reports on the same site deployment before. I am not 100% on what settings or properties of the report cause this to happen but figured it was worth throwing out there.

Comment: I checked my source: and i found the following:Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts.

Comment: b)The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file,

Comment: or add <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /&gt; to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

Comment: but I had the latter already..any idea from here?

Comment: @Richa Any updates with this issue? Have you solved the blank screen issue? If so how ? Or still problem there. Since i am also facing same problem for some reports (long running querry)

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps in `IIS`:
 Open `IIS`. Go to > Application pools. Right click your application pool. Select '**Set application pool defaults**'. Update following :

1. Idle timeout (minutes): Give 20 min
2. Maximum worker processes:  Set this as 1. ( The actual reason behind the issue is , in case of multiple worker processes, the
   handler can't find expected session state data in case we requests
   for second time.

   3. Set private memory limit and virtual memory limit to zero (0).

Hope it will work :)

Comment: Point one was one of the things we include. Besides that actually adding AsyncPostBackTimeout property in the asp.net page having the report viewer control finally resolved the issue-<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  AsyncPostBackTimeout="0">
 </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: Thanks @Richa. Adding AsyncPostBackTimeout="0" to asp:ScriptManager tag helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just recompile the stored procedure that is being used in rdl.

Hope it will resolved your problem.